# Python survival analysis - start / stop format question

Tags: pandas, numpy, data-science, survival-analysis

I am new to data science and I have a rather simple question, but I cannot find a simple answer for it...

I have a dataset (hospital patients) on which I want to perform survival analysis. This dataset is left-censored and right truncated and has the following format:

Let's say PersonId = 30 has 4 measurements (rows)

​

| PersonID | ObservationDate | Event | Covariate1 | Covariate... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | 2019-05-01 15:27:44 | False | Int | Int |
| 30 | 2019-05-02 01:57:16 | True | Int | Int |
| 30 | 2019-05-02 03:19:01 | False | Int | Int |
| 30 | 302019-05-02 05:16:49 | True | Int | Int |

I want to convert this to a table that has start-stop columns, which would translate to:

​

| PersonID | ObservationDate | Event | start | stop | Covariate1 | Covariate... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | 2019-05-01 15:27:44 | False | 0 | 2019-05-01 15:27:44 | Int | Int |
| 30 | 2019-05-02 01:57:16 | True | 2019-05-01 15:27:44 | 2019-05-02 01:57:16 | Int | Int |
| 30 | 2019-05-02 03:19:01 | False | 2019-05-02 01:57:16 | 2019-05-02 03:19:01 | Int | Int |
| 30 | 2019-05-02 05:16:49 | True | 2019-05-02 03:19:01 | 2019-05-02 05:16:49 | Int | Int |

However, I cannot figure out how to do this without losing a row. The above is nonsensical, as start "0" is meaningless. The other alternative makes no sense either, as there would be no stop.

Any help would be appreciated.

Quick edit: R or Python solutions are preferred.

Comment: You can not guess information that you do not have, what are you trying to do ?

Comment: @obchardon Basically predict when an event will occur depending on the covariates.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly. (Imagine that ObservationDate is actually a  timestamp)

```
dict = {'PersonID': [30]*4, 'ObservationDate': [10,20,35,45], 'Event': [False,True,False,True]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
print(df)

   PersonID  ObservationDate  Event
0        30               10  False
1        30               20   True
2        30               35  False
3        30               45   True

df['start'] = df['ObservationDate'].shift(periods=1).fillna(0)
df['end'] = df['ObservationDate']
print(df)

    PersonID    ObservationDate     Event   start   end
0         30                 10     False     0.0    10
1         30                 20     True     10.0    20
2         30                 35     False    20.0    35
3         30                 45     True     35.0    45
```